# how to check for more than one variable in a `case`?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

i wonder if it is somehow possible to use more than one variable in a case statement, so i don't have to maintain the numerous lines (which should be identical) twice?

for example i want to check if one (or both is also fine) of `LC_ALL` or `LANG` start with `es`:
*as i'm using the logical "or" (`||`) in the pseudo code, i would expect it work as usual in the shell... check if the first variable matches any case, if not check if the second matches any case.*

```bash
case "${LC_ALL}" || "${LANG}" in    # something like this would come in handy
  "es"*)
    # numerous lines ABC
  ;;
  "VALUE1" | "VALUE2")              # i know 2 different VALUES are possible, but not helpful in my situation
    # numerous lines XYZ
  ;;
esac
```

for sure i've read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-case and searched the web for some similar examples but unfortunately found nothing in this regard.
and yes, i also found [Multiple variables in a CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646825/multiple-variables-in-a-case-statement) but somehow it seems to be a completely different approach (which i don't get completely).

**bonus question:** why is only 1 vertical bar (`|`) used between 2 values and not 2 (`||`) like it is as a logical "or" at commands and the like?

Comment: Just to tighten the logic: Are the variables supposed to have a precedence, i.e. what should happen if one variable matches one pattern, and the other one another?

Comment: @pmf: IMHO simply the same as it is done for commands would be logical... that's why i mentioned and used the logical "or": if the first variable matches a case go for it, if not evaluate the second.

Comment: Regarding the bonus question, it is just the syntax related to the `case`-statement. The case statement has no concept of and-or.

Comment: I don't understand the question: Do you want to test that one of these two assertions hold: (1) "LC_ALL has either VALUE1 or VALUE2" , (2) "LANG has either VALUE1 or VALUE2"?

Comment: @user1934428: forget `VALUE[12]`...  i just wanted to make clear, that i'm **not** looking for a way to check for different values (see the comment), but for a way to take 2 different variables into account (the first line is the one that matters)!

Comment: Sure, but it is still not clear whether you want to test, that EXACTLY ONE of these variables have the required value, or that AT LEAST ONE of these variables have the required value, or that BOTH variables have that value.

Comment: @user1934428: for sure... that's why i used `||` which is usually the logical "or" (as explained in my first comment). -- if both variables must have the same value i would have used `&&` and for that there would be an easy workaround by checking if they are equal beforehand and then use one of them in the `case`. but i'll give you that... the situation where only exactly one of the variables should match, would be difficult.

Comment: @kvantour what a pity that it hasn't... so basically just another inconsistency resp. incoherence.

Comment: Well, I asked you which of three possibilities you want to achieve, and you answer with "for sure". This does not make clear, which possibility you are refering to. BTW, such clarification should go into the question (you can edit the question), not into a comment. BTW, if you read the man page of bash, in particular about the `case` statement, you will see that `||` does not have any specific meaning. There is no point in using it here.

Comment: @user1934428 well... 1) sorry for answering directly to you. i just thought it is a polite thing to do (and AFAIK you also get a notification that way). **--** 2) i did go into all 3 possibilities of you question and also mentioned that i already explained what i expect the pseudo code to do resp. loosely answered your question in my first comment. **--** 3) i would appreciate if you at least read the mentioned comments or the already improved question before complaining about not answering your questions resp. not editing my question.

Comment: @user1934428 4) the `||` is more or less the whole point of the question! i use **pseudo code** which **does not exist** (and explained afterwards in greater detail what i expect it to do, as it seems not that clear to some) to describe a feature/logic/result i would like to have. ...and ask if resp. how it is possible to achieve the result otherwise as **the feature does not exist**. -> e.g. see the unaltered comment in the first line of the code: *"something **like** this **would** come in handy"*.

Comment: Ah, in this case, it would have been IMO be more clear that you use pseudocode which does not resemble bash code, as it would be less confusing. It is fine if you ask how to implement such a "feature", but I still don't see a precise definition of what you want. For instance, you could show how you would currently implement it in bash (using a series of `if` statements), and then ask if we can somehow squeeze this into a `case` statement.

Comment: Re: `||` vs `|` -- think of it as more like regex alternation syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Code which doesn't do what you want is not a good way to explain what you actually want. Perhaps you are looking for

```
case ${LC_ALL}${LANG} in
  *"es"* )
    # numerous lines
  ;;
  *"VALUE"[12]*)
    # numerous lines
  ;;
esac
```

If you want to ensure that you are examining the whole value, maybe try

```
case :${LC_ALL}:${LANG}: in
  *:"es"* )  # or perhaps *:"es":*?
    # numerous lines
  ;;
  *:"VALUE"[12]:*)
    # numerous lines
  ;;
esac
```

(where of course if the value could contain a colon, probably choose a different delimiter. In the near-duplicate, they were using a plus for this).

... Or, perhaps you mean

```
for value in "$LANG" "$LC_ALL"; do
    case $value in
      "es"* )
        # numerous lines
        break
      ;;
      "VALUE"[12] )
        # numerous lines
        break
      ;;
    esac
done
```

where perhaps you'd also want to arrange some sort of fallback if neither of the values matched any of the patterns; perhaps try this slightly more elaborate version:

```
found=""

for value in "$LANG" "$LC_ALL"; do
    case $value in
      "es"* )
        # numerous lines
        found=$value
        break
      ;;
      "VALUE"[12] )
        # numerous lines
        found=$value
        break
      ;;
    esac
done
case $found in
    '') echo "$0: catastrophic failure! Red alert! Mayhem!" >&2
        exit 69;;
esac
```

If you want to keep track of which *variable* matched rather than which value, perhaps also look at [indirect expansion.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411)

I don't think there is a good reason for the syntax to prefer `|` over `||` but there is no good reason to do the opposite, either. The alternatives are glob patterns, not commands. `x | y` already meant something else so they had to use `||` between commands for OR, but there is no such limitation for globs.

Comment: 1) yes i knew the possibility of using `VALUE[12]`, but wanted to make it crystal clear that i'm not asking about different values. ...and as we are at it, i wanted to mention resp. ask about the vertical bar incoherence in one swoop. ;-) **--** 2) ok... now as you are mentioning delimiter, also the other question somehow begins to make sense.

Comment: See updated answer now.

Comment: the last one is a nice construct to get something like an else-case. +1 **--** in situations where no matching case is even the default which does not alter the result and doesn't produce any output by itself, IMHO it's sufficient to place it right before the for-loop and if a case matches, it gets overwritten anyway.

Comment: `"VALUE[12]")` is not the same case as `"VALUE1" | "VALUE2")` - the quotes disable the bracketed character class, instead turning it into a literal.

Comment: @amphetamachine Duh, thanks, I can't believe I missed that! Updated

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting the gist of what you're *actually* trying to accomplish, there's a more robust way of doing it.

You probably want to use the common *nix program `locale` to get the language name (part of the `libc-bin` [Ubuntu], or `glibc` package [Slackware]).

This program reads `LC_ALL` and `LANG` and `LC_MESSAGES` in some order I'm not privy to and calculates what settings should be applied in a standardized way. **If you try to re-implement `locale` in your shell script, you're going to have a bad time.**

Then you only have to key off of one subshell expansion:

```bash
case $(locale lang_ab) in
    'en')
        ;;
    'es')
        ;;
esac
```

You can key off the full language name too.

```bash
case $(locale language) in
    *'English') # en_US, en_NZ, en_CA, en_GB, etc.
        ;;
    *'Spanish') # es_ES, es_CO, es_EU, es_MX, etc.
        ;;
esac
```

If you so desire, you can also key off individual language names:

```bash
case $(locale language) in
    'American English') # i.e. en_US
        ;;
    'Mexican Spanish') # i.e. es_MX
        ;;
    'European Spanish') # i.e. es_ES
        ;;
esac
```

You can ask `locale` for all sorts of things, such as how the user's locale settings specify how to format numbers and dates. Even how to say 'yes' to the user:

```bash
$ LANG=en_US locale yesstr
yes
$ LANG=es_ES locale yesstr
sí
```

More keywords can be found under [`locale(5)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/locale.5.html) (`man 5 locale`)

But, if you're going for simplicity, or you don't have `locale` installed, you can use `${LC_ALL:-$LANG}` to mean "default to `$LANG` if `$LC_ALL` is unset or empty":

```bash
case ${LC_ALL:-$LANG} in
  'es'*)
  ;;
  'VALUE1' | 'VALUE2')
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Good point. For what it's worth, the argument to `case` does not need to be quoted; this is unobvious and trivial, but still true.

Comment: @tripleee My tests confirm you're right - it *doesn't* need to be quoted. I did not know that! :-D